# Substitute function of bwdist in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, euclidean-distance

I am implementing a code of Matlab in C++. In Matlab they have used **bwdist** to calculate the euclidean distance.

I am using the function **distanceTransform** to get the same result as in Matlab, but the results are drastically different.

```
float tests[5][5] = {{0, 0, 0, 0,0},{0, 0, 0, 0,0},{0, 0, 1, 0,0},{0, 0, 0, 0,0},{0 , 0 , 0 , 0,0}};
    Mat test(5,5,CV_8UC1,&tests);
    Mat test_result = Mat::zeros(5,5,CV_32FC1);
    distanceTransform(test,test_result,CV_DIST_L1,3);
```

C++ Result is given below.

```
test_result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

All zeros while using in OpenCV.
Whereas the Matlab Result is something different.

```
  2.8284    2.2361    2.0000    2.2361    2.8284
  2.2361    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    2.2361
  2.0000    1.0000         0    1.0000    2.0000
  2.2361    1.4142    1.0000    1.4142    2.2361
  2.8284    2.2361    2.0000    2.2361    2.8284
```

Please suggest me some way to get the same result in C++/OpenCv too, as there is in Matlab.

Comment: For equivalency with MATLAB, your code should look like `distanceTransform(test,test_result,CV_DIST_L2,CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE );`. However, I cannot make it work on OpenCV either ; this could be a bug.

Comment: No its not working with this also. It is giving same result as tests.

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 1, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0]

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my comment ; it does not work even with the correct arguments.

Comment: Is there any other solution, for this problem ?

Comment: Lol ; there is no problem. MATLAB's `bwdist` finds the *distance between that pixel and the nearest nonzero pixel* and OpenCV's `distanceTransform` finds *the distance to the closest zero pixel for each pixel*. So follow @agrum's code, and you should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, next time before writing an answer, I'll read thoroughly the documentation. In the first versions I used the same input matrix as the MatLab one so it couldn't work as expected. But to the OP, next time read the doc before asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dare say the function works. Next time feed your matrices with proper data.

```
uchar tests[5][5] = { //You create a 8UC1, so your data set type should match
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {1 ,1, 1, 1, 1}};
Mat test(5, 5, CV_8UC1, tests); //tests is already a pointer
Mat test_result;
distanceTransform(test, test_result, CV_DIST_L2, 3); //You want euclidian distance
```

Comment: It is not working. I checked it. The result now it is giving is

     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
     0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
     0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0]

Comment: I didn't notice you used `CV_DIST_L1` instead of `CV_DIST_L2`. Also I don't have opencv installed nor ever worked with it. So far the answer is just based on what the doc says.

Comment: Its not working again. Actually documents says that the function will calculate the euclidean distance, but it is not doing so.

[0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0.95432, 0, 0; 0, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 0] 

This is the result after changing to CV_DIST_L2 from CV_DIST_L1.

Comment: because it computes the distance to the closest zero. As writen in the documentation. Your input matrix is wrong. If you expect the same result as MatLab, the middle should be zero, the surrounding 1.

Comment: I would suggest to use CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE so get the exact result as of Matlab as said by Jacob too. because writing 3 instead of CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE doesn't give exact result.

Comment: "Typically, for a fast, coarse distance estimation CV_DIST_L2, a 3\times 3 mask is used. For a more accurate distance estimation CV_DIST_L2 , a 5\times 5 mask or the precise algorithm is used. Note that both the precise and the approximate algorithms are linear on the number of pixels.". If precision is your target yes. If you look for speed keep 3.